# Error CS0840 in MSBuild but not in VS2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, msbuild

I have the following code:

```
    namespace NS{
    public class ClassName{
        public PropertyName{get;}
}
}
```

I get the following error:

> TestFile.cs(11,32): error CS0840: 'NS.ClassName.PropertyName.get' must
>   declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern.
>   Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set
>   accessors.

When compiled in VS2015 everything is working good. When trying to build using MSBuild the error happens.

I am compiling against .NET 4.6.2 with C# 6.0 and ToolsVersion 14.0.

What am I missing?

Comment: Show us the code... (though I suspect MSBuild is old and trying to compile with C# v5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is almost certainly happening here is that your version of MSBuild is old and is compiling against version 5 of C#. Consider this code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = 1;
    }

    public int Bar { get; }
}
```

This will compile happily in C# 6 (i.e. VS2015) but will throw the error you experience from MSBuild (and also if you used VS2013.)

If you want to compile with MSBuild then you need to download and install the updated build tools: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Comment: I downloaded the new build tool but for some reason it(an automated build app) used the one that came with .net framework. Thanks